# 0 test class found in package ‘<default package>’

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have recently installed IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.4 and the jRebel plugin. I have licensed it ok and created and added configurations in `catalina.bat` file.

When running jRebel from within IntelliJ, it seems to be monitoring the correct directories but I get the following message:

> 0 test class found in package ‘’

This then tells me that it has failed to start.

Does anybody know what I might need to change to get this to work?

Comment: Btw this doesn't seem to be a jRebel specific question

Comment: Happened because I accidentally selected run as junit for testng tests.

Answer (score 33):

Make sure your class is declared as public and not 'default'

```
public class MyClassTest
```

as opposed to:

```
class MyClassTest
```

When creating a new test class via IntelliJ shortcut the generated class was not declared as public and that caused the error.

Comment: Why does IntelliJ do this if it forcibly leads to errors?!

Comment: I believe IntelliJ only does this when you create the test in the same source folder and package. Just tested this with creating a second test after fixing the first, and after creating a test source folder, and now the `public` is present automatically.

Answer (score 27):

This can be fixed by [invalidating the cache](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/cleaning-system-cache.html).

On the main menu, choose <kbd>File</kbd> -> <kbd>Invalidate Caches/Restart</kbd>.

[Source](https://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/454231)

Comment: Links to external sites can go down over time. If you have found information that is relevant to the question, please consider re-writing it yourself or quoting the page you have linked to within your answer.

Comment: True `On the main menu, choose File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart` works. Thanks :)

Comment: Not working for me, however run individual test class working as usual.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

On your topbar or Alt + Shift + F10 and Run your project with your default Configuration not "values in app"

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Make sure 'app' is selected to run...

Answer (score 1):

When I used the IntelliJ 'Create Test' feature, my test classes were automatically created as private.

When I manually changed my test classes to public, my test classes were found.

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/javahelp/comments/4ca825/intellij_junit4_0_test_classes_found/?st=ixec25w2&sh=8e1fa458)

Comment: That's not much of a technical answer. If you're not providing a legitimate technical solution and something is that brief and requires so little effort, please just post it as a comment below the question.

Comment: Flagged "Low Quality"

Comment: Granted I didn't have the exact same situation as specified in the question, but this answer actually worked for me! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Just create **another folder**, which will mark the directory as **Sources Root** and move your executable file into this folder.

Answer (score 1):

For me this was the problem: My test folder was `./test/src/com/...`. I had marked `test` as test folder, but `test/src` was the right one.

The "false" setting worked for me with Jintellij 2017.1.3, but not in 2018.02.

Comment: I did the same, but in my case I had to mark test/java as my "Test Sources Root". This fixed it for me (well, my tests are now running with all kinds of errors, which is better than being told it can't find any tests).

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was deleting the .idea folder and importing the project again.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and for me it was because TestNG plugin was not installed in Intellij. I did not choose it when installed Intellij and forgot about that.