# sbt scalatest returning '0 test class found in package '<default package>''

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, scalatest, typesafe-activator

I pulled the 'test-patterns-scala' Typesafe Activator template. Once loaded into Intellij 13.1.5 I right-clicked on the test/scala directory and selected 'Run->All Tests' this returned the output :

> 0 test class found in package '

There is also a popup which says:

> Tests were not found in module 'test-patterns-scala', Use module "test-patterns-scala-build" instead

This is my first stackoverflow post, I searched for similar problems and only found the unanswered link below, however I couldn't up-vote it as a first time poster and the circumstances are a little different so I thought a new question was justified. Any help much appreciated!

Link to similar post: [0 test class found in package ‘<default package>’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770563/0-test-class-found-in-package-default-package)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a while ago. I got a fix by running 'sbt test' from the command line for the first go (in the project directory ofcourse).

After this the IntelliJ didn't have any problem in identifying the package and ran the test.